# html video background is not playing online

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a background video which plays offline as it's expected but it's not playing online.
this is the html code:

```
<video autoplay poster="vid/TD.jpg" id="bgVid" loop>
    <source src="vid/TD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </source>
</video>
```

[this](http://topdesignstudio.ir/) is the actual website itself if you want to see it so for your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your markup looks correct, but the video is coming through as a 404. Double check your path to the video and the capitalization of the file name, too. Resolve that, and I bet your video starts working.